# View DNS Suffix list

Tags: windows-7, dns, powershell, ms-dos

I am local administrator on my PC, but I cannot view my DNS Suffixes.

[image]

I just want to be able to view them. Is there another way to see them?
I am on Windows 7 64-bit Enterprise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can issue the command

```
ipconfig /all
```

in a `cmd.exe` shell. In the section *Windows IP Configuration* the suffixes are usually shown.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Please note that if your machine is connected to an AD DS domain, these settings will be controlled by domain admins via group policies. You have not mentioned the environment. Or have you disconnected it from an enterprise network? I am trying to clarify because there are some pre-defined lists already in the list. DNS suffix for this connection does not need to appear if its assigned externally. In this case, you cannot select any. Just selecting the IP Addresses on the top, you won't see any such details. Connection specific DNS suffixes can be found using IPCONFIG as well. With the Switch /ALL (IPCONFIG /ALL). However,  it will display only if available. Hope this helps.